# Can I run a docker container with GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

I'm want to perform CI with tests that depends on a container that is published in Docker Hub. Is it possible? Can I start the container and run tests that depends on it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, here is an example using docker-compose:

```
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Login to Docker Registry
        run: docker login "$DOCKER_REGISTRY" -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin <<< "$DOCKER_PASSWORD"
        env:
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          DOCKER_REGISTRY: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}
      - name: Start env
        run: docker-compose up
      - name: Run tests
        run: ...
```

Comment: Excellent. It seems all we need is `docker run`. And we can login to our own repo if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Change image, username and password**

```
jobs:
  use-container:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: registry.gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer:latest
      credentials:
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
    steps:
      - name: Run in container
        run: | # Example
          echo This job does specify a container.
          pwd
          cd /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin
          ls
          psql --version
```